# JS Userscript: accessing DOM of new tab

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts, browser-extension

I'm writing a Chrome userscript to open a new tab, then click on some DOM elements. But how can I access the DOM of the new tab?

```
/* background script */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.create({"url": MY_URL, (tab) => {
    // What ought I to do?
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have at least one [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) file loaded in your tab (with the right permissions to allow the content script to be loaded).
In the content script, you will have to leverage the [Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate with the background page.

If your logic is simple enough, you could even run all logic directly inside content script, as they have access to be same set of chrome API as the background page.